# SpriteKit collision detection on multiple objects of the same type

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am currently working on a game with a friend right now using Objective-C and SpriteKit. My friend and I are both new to SpriteKit, so this project we are working on is more of just a learning experience. But of course, we are running in to some trouble.

The game is fairly simple: There is a ball that fly's around the screen and bounces off of the "walls", or edges of the iPhone screen. The user controls a paddle at the bottom of the screen to deflect the ball back up to prevent the ball from reaching the bottom of the screen. Each time the ball hits the paddle, the score counter at the top of the screen increments by one.

Here is what we are struggling to accomplish. When the score of the game is equal to 5, we add a new ball to the scene. That new ball begins to move by itself, but whenever we try to detect if that new ball has hit an edge of the screen, the collision is not being detected.

Here is our method which returns a ball object:

```
+(id)ball
{
    // the ball is a random image from google
    Ball *ball = [Ball spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];

    // set the position of the ball
    ball.position = CGPointMake(0, 80);

    // set ball name property
    ball.name = @"ball";

    // give the ball a physics body
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ball.size];

    ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    return ball;
}
```

This method is called to move the balls in the scene:

```
-(void)move:(int)deltaX withDeltaY:(int)deltaY
{
    SKAction *testMoveRight = [SKAction moveByX:deltaX y:deltaY duration:0.03];

    // this will repeat the action over and over
    SKAction *move = [SKAction repeatActionForever:testMoveRight];
    [self runAction:move];
}
```

These are our categories for collision detection:

```
// this category is for the original ball in the game
static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x1 << 0;
// this category is for the second ball that gets added to the game
static const uint32_t ball2Category = 0x1 << 1;  
static const uint32_t paddleCategory = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t topBarrierCategory = 0x1 << 3;
static const uint32_t leftBarrierCategory = 0x1 << 4;
static const uint32_t rightBarrierCategory = 0x1 << 5;
static const uint32_t gameOverBarrierCategory = 0x1 << 6;
```

And here is our didBeginContact method:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }


    // first ball contact
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ballCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & rightBarrierCategory) != 0) {
        [ball move:-15 withDeltaY:0];
    }

    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ballCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & topBarrierCategory) != 0) {
        [ball move:0 withDeltaY:-20];
    }

    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ballCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & leftBarrierCategory) != 0) {
        [ball move:15 withDeltaY:0];
    }

    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ballCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & paddleCategory) != 0) {
        [ball move:0 withDeltaY:20];

        // increment score
        self.score++; 
        // update the score label
        self.deathLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.score];

        // add a new ball to the scene if the score is 5
        if (score == 5) {
            [scene addChild:ball2];
            [ball2 move:5 withDeltaY:10];
        }
    }

    // second ball contact detection
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ball2Category) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & rightBarrierCategory) != 0) {
        [ball2 move:-15 withDeltaY:0];
    }
}
```

Why doesn't that second ball we add to the scene detect when it is colliding with the right barrier (right edge of the screen)? When it reaches the right edge of the screen, it doesn't bounce off and move left like we want it to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to simply add a physicsBody to the ball, you must also set category, contact, and collision bitmasks. First, I would change the physicsBody of the ball to

`ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2];`

Circular physics bodies are first more efficient, and second better for your case. Along with this, you do not need a separate category for each barrier. Combine them all into one:

```
self.size = self.view.bounds.size;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, self.frame.size.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path , NULL, self.frame.size.width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
SKShapeNode *bounds = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path];
bounds.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
bounds.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boundsCategory;
```

As you can see, each SpriteNode has a categoryBitmask, and it has either a collision bitmask (which means it bounces/collides with these categories) and a contact bitmask (I did not set one here, but when this contact occurs, the didBeginContact method is called). In your code, the didBeginContact method will not get called, but you also do not need it for bouncing. To clarify, the bounciness will happen on its own, meaning that you do not need any contact methods or bitmasks, simply apply a force/impulse to the ball and as it touches the bounds it will bounce.

As for the ball, you do not need another category for each ball - this is redundancy. For each ball created, just set the categoryBitmask to the same thing:

```
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = boundsCategory;
```

By adding these lines, you are telling the compiler that each ball is of 'ballCategory' and that it should collide with ANY object that is 'boundsCategory'. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any idea whether I could set the ball's physicsbody to not lose "speed" when it bounces off of a barrier, and allow it to move in the opposite direction? I have set the ball's categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask as you suggested above, but eventually after bouncing off of a couple of barriers the ball loses its speed. Any suggestions? I'm still a bit confused on how I should use the didBeginContact method.

Comment: didBeginContact is used when you want a method to be called when two objects contact each other (the objects won't bounce off of each other, the didBeginContact will simply get called but the objects will continue to move/do their thing). For the ball to continuously bounce, set its restitution to 1.0f:

`ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f`
Restitution is a value of 'bounciness' where 1.0f means it will never lose speed when bouncing and 0.0f means as soon as it collides it stops (0 bounce). If this answers your question, I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: As for moving in the opposite direction, you may need to specify exactly what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This almost seems to make it work the way we want it to be. I adjusted the ball's restitution to 1.0f, and when I apply an impulse to the ball, it seems to work for the first several bounces, but eventually the ball loses it's speed in the y direction and starts to slow down to an eventual stop. The ball continues to move at the same speed in the x direction, however. Any suggestions on how to maintain this speed in the y direction? And what I meant earlier by "moving in the opposite direction" was maintaining the ball's bounciness as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; the loss of speed in the Y direction may be due to gravity acting on the sprite. Did you set `ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;`?

Comment: No worries. And yes I have already set the ball's physics body to not be affected by gravity. The ball will bounce off each barrier, but will slowly lose its momentum until an eventual where it gets stuck in place. I have tried messing around with the physics world's gravity, but nothing really seems to be working in my favor. I also played around with the didBeginContact method, and set it so that an impulse was applied to the ball when the ball made contact with the paddle, but that only made the ball move very irregularly. Sorry if I'm not being clear enough with what's going on!

Comment: No problem. Try setting it's friction to 0.0 as well

Comment: I finally figured it out! Instead of creating separate categorybitmasks for each ball (which is redundant, like you said), I created one categorybitmask for all of the balls. Then, in didBeginContact, instead of writing separate code to check for the collision of each ball, I just applied an impulse to the body that made contact with the paddle (much easier and simple than what I was trying to do). Thanks for your help though, your suggestions will definitely help me out in the future!